# When is "Constant" class variable initialized

Tags: c#, .net

I have a constant int variable defined as a class variable:

My class is defined like this:

```
public class ABC : XYZ
{
    private const int constantNumber = 600;

    public ABC(): base(constantNumber)
    {}

}
```

Would it be available by the time it calls the base constructor (i.e. before calling it's own constructor)?

When exactly does it get defined?

Comment: @Default If I had initial confidence in my comment I likely would have.

Comment: @Default comments are used when one doesn't have the time or the inclination to post a full answer

Comment: @Default Plus if I know the venerable Mr Skeet is going to answer, I quite often don't bother (for obvious reasons) ;-)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I really disagree.. I agree with the reasoning from [here](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/72) **Comments are not for answers**

Comment: @Default I agree with you, and I think he was being sarcastic. I am guilty of posting comment answers when I don't have the time in the office, but I still want to help someone. Another community member can then come along, take my comment and make an answer of it in the fullness of time.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I wasn't being sarcastic if you meant me. I agree with your comment though. If I don't have the time to post a full answer (I have to work after all), I'll post at least what I can.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In that case I still agree with Default, this isn't when to use comments, it is just how one may abuse the system to offer help when there is a paucity of time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's available even without the class being initialized! Basically, everywhere the constant is used, the compiler will inline the value.

For example:

```
public class Constants
{
    public const int Foo = 10;

    static Constants()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Constants is being initialized");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // This won't provoke "Constants is being initialized"
        Console.WriteLine(Constants.Foo);
        // The IL will be exactly equivalent to:
        // Console.WriteLine(10);
    }
}
```

Even with a `static readonly` variable, you'd still be able to use it where you're currently using it - because it's related to the type rather than an instance of the type. Don't forget that `const` is implicitly `static` (and you can't state that explicitly).

As a side note (mentioned in comments) this "embedding" means that you should only use `const` for things which really *are* constants. If `Constants` and `Program` above were in different assemblies, and `Constant.Foo` were changed to have a value of 20, then `Program` would need to be recompiled before the change would be usable. That *isn't* the case with a `static readonly` field, whose value is retrieved at execution time instead of being embedded at compile time.

(This also affects default values for optional parameters.)

Comment: Which is a risk when the constant is used in a different assembly. If the constant is changed, the using assembly may not be recompiled.

Comment: @MarkO: Indeed. At that point calling it a "constant" is dubious :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, technically this trait makes it more "constant" than before, just in an unwanted fashion :-)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: That's my point: you shouldn't use `const` for a value that isn't *truly* a constant, because the semantics are designed for real constants.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh right, well, I'm glad we're on the same page :-)

Comment: I think `private const` is always ok, even if the value might change in the future.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Yes, on the grounds that it will *always* be only visible within the same assembly.

Answer (score 4):

At compile time, it is compiled directly into the resulting DLL so is available long before the program even starts running.

As MarkO points out, when a constant is used in assembly B from A, the value from A is compiled directly into B. So if you updated and redeployed A with value change, B would not reflect it.